# Data Validation list from filtering 2 columns with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this problem and I do not know how to solve it. So:

I have an 3 columns with different data: ex():

ColA    ColB    ColC

FPROC   C5  V-250396

FPROC   C4  V-250396

FPROC   C4  V-250396

FPROC   C4  V-250397

FPROC   C4  V-250397

FPROC   C4  V-250398

FPROC   C4  V-250398

FPROC   C4  V-250399

FPROC   C4  V-250399

FPROC   H1  V-250400

FPROC   H1  V-250400

FPROC   H2  V-250401

FPROC   H3  V-250402

JISBL   C5  V-250403

JISBL   C4  V-250404

JISBL   H1  V-250405

JISBL   H2  V-250406

JISBL   C4  V-250405

JISBL   H2  V-250407

on cell D1 I will have an validation list based from ColA values

on cell E1 I will have an validation list based from ColB values filtred with colA value

on cell F1 I will have an validation list based from ColC values filtred with colA value and ColB value.

Example:

I chose on D1: FPROC >> on cell E1 I will have a DV(data validation list): C5,C4,H1,H2,H3

I chose on E1: C4 >> on cell F1 I would like to have a DV: V-250396,V-250397,V-250398,V-250399

So based on selection from D1+E1 to have in F1 the correct values of DV.

I have the following code that it is working for the first (D1) and second (E1) DV but for the last one (F1) it is not working well.

Any suggestion to find the correct values? (Thank you!)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, n As Long
    Dim MyCol As Collection
    Dim SearchString As String, TempList As String

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error GoTo WTF

    'LastRow in Col A
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        Set MyCol = New Collection

        'data from Col A into a collection
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If Len(Trim(Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                MyCol.Add CStr(Range("A" & i).Value), CStr(Range("A" & i).Value)
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next i

        'list for the DV List
        For n = 1 To MyCol.Count
            TempList = TempList & "," & MyCol(n)
        Next

        TempList = Mid(TempList, 2)

        Range("D1").ClearContents: Range("D1").Validation.Delete
        Range("E1").ClearContents: Range("E1").Validation.Delete

        ' Create the DV List
        If Len(Trim(TempList)) <> 0 Then
            With Range("D1").Validation
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=TempList
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If
    '~~> Capturing change in cell D1
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("D1")) Is Nothing Then

        SearchString = Range("D1").Value


        TempList = FindRange(Range("A1:A" & LastRow), SearchString)
        TempList = RemoveDuplicates(TempList)

        Range("E1").ClearContents: Range("E1").Validation.Delete

        If Len(Trim(TempList)) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Create the DV List
            With Range("E1").Validation
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=TempList
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If
    '~~> Capturing change in cell E1
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E1")) Is Nothing Then
        SearchString = Range("E1").Value

        TempList = FindRange(Range("B1:B" & LastRow), SearchString)
        TempList = RemoveDuplicates(TempList)

        Range("F1").ClearContents: Range("F1").Validation.Delete

        If Len(Trim(TempList)) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Create the DV List
            With Range("F1").Validation
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=TempList
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If

    End If


LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
WTF:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub

Function FindRange(FirstRange As Range, StrSearch As String) As String
    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, oRange As Range
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Dim strTemp As String

    Set aCell = FirstRange.Find(what:=StrSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    ExitLoop = False

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell
        strTemp = strTemp & "," & aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = FirstRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                'strTemp = strTemp & Application.International(xlListSeparator) & aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
                strTemp = strTemp & "," & aCell.Offset(, 1).Value
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
        FindRange = Mid(strTemp, 2)
    End If
End Function

Function RemoveDuplicates(str As String) As String

Dim aryInitial As Variant
Dim strFinal As String
Dim i As Long

aryInitial = Split(str, ",")

For i = LBound(aryInitial) To UBound(aryInitial)
    If InStr(strFinal, Trim(aryInitial(i))) = 0 Then
        strFinal = strFinal & aryInitial(i) & ","
    End If
Next i

RemoveDuplicates = strFinal

End Function
```

Comment: For the tertiary validation list in F1, your example above shows duplicate values.  Do you really want that?

Comment: Duplicate values will be removed (was a typo mistake in example).

Comment: I remove duplicate from example (now, maybe is clearer).

Comment: Another example: I have in ColA: Apple, Pears, Apricot, Apple, Pears. ColB: Red, Yellow, Green, Orange, Red. ColC: 1,2,3,4,5
If I choose in D1 Apple in E1 will be Red and Orange. if I choose Red then in F1 I like to have 1 instead 1, 5 (like it is now)

Comment: The code I posted in my answer also seems to handle your fruit example as required; showing only the 1 in the DV dropdown list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your solution (excel sheet).
I try a different approach (much easier from my point of view). I put this as an answer because the code is different then yours. I do not explained (the code) because your experience knows to read what is inside. Please tell me your point of view (thank you!).

This is the file: [excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qs1QnelGmyaW94cGRHSXVHRXc/edit?usp=sharing)

This is the  code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim MyCol As Collection
    Dim SearchString As String, TempList As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim j As Integer

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error GoTo WTF

    'LastRow in Col A
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim matrice(LastRow, 2) As String

        Set MyCol = New Collection

        'data from Col A into a collection
        For i = 1 To LastRow
            If Len(Trim(Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                MyCol.Add CStr(Range("A" & i).Value), CStr(Range("A" & i).Value)
                matrice(i - 1, 0) = CStr(Range("A" & i).Value)
                matrice(i - 1, 1) = Range("A" & i).Offset(, 1).Value
                matrice(i - 1, 2) = Range("A" & i).Offset(, 2).Value
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next i

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        'list for the DV List
        For n = 1 To MyCol.Count
            TempList = TempList & "," & MyCol(n)
        Next


        TempList = Mid(TempList, 2)

        Range("D1").ClearContents: Range("D1").Validation.Delete
        Range("E1").ClearContents: Range("E1").Validation.Delete
        Range("F1").ClearContents: Range("F1").Validation.Delete

        ' Create the DV List
        If Len(Trim(TempList)) <> 0 Then
            With Range("D1").Validation
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=TempList
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If
    '~~> Capturing change in cell D1
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("D1")) Is Nothing Then

        For j = LBound(matrice) To UBound(matrice) - 1
           If matrice(j, 0) = Range("D1").Value Then
               TempList = TempList & "," & matrice(j, 1)
           End If
        Next j

        TempList = RemoveDuplicates(TempList)

        Range("E1").ClearContents: Range("E1").Validation.Delete
        Range("F1").ClearContents: Range("F1").Validation.Delete

        If Len(Trim(TempList)) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Create the DV List
            With Range("E1").Validation
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=TempList
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If
    '~~> Capturing change in cell E1
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("E1")) Is Nothing Then

        For j = LBound(matrice) To UBound(matrice) - 1
           If matrice(j, 0) = Range("D1").Value And matrice(j, 1) = Range("E1").Value Then
               TempList = TempList & "," & matrice(j, 2)
           End If
        Next j

        TempList = RemoveDuplicates(TempList)

        Range("F1").ClearContents: Range("F1").Validation.Delete

        If Len(Trim(TempList)) <> 0 Then
            '~~> Create the DV List
            With Range("F1").Validation
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=TempList
                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
            End With
        End If

    End If
LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
WTF:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
Function RemoveDuplicates(str As String) As String

Dim aryInitial As Variant
Dim strFinal As String
Dim i As Long

aryInitial = Split(str, ",")

For i = LBound(aryInitial) To UBound(aryInitial)
    If InStr(strFinal, Trim(aryInitial(i))) = 0 Then
        strFinal = strFinal & aryInitial(i) & ","
    End If
Next i

RemoveDuplicates = strFinal

End Function
```

Comment: If your code works, and does everything you need it to, then use it.  There are many different ways to solve an Excel problem.  You need to pick what works best for you.

Comment: Having just today been able to download your file, to me a major disadvantage would be that your code can allow combinations in D1:F1 that should not be allowed.  See this screen shot ![Illegal Combo](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8EDB73C8A1A37A69!470&authkey=!AFWjT14RuhCcIsY&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng)

Comment: Hello, Ron. I was looking again to the code but in my case it is working (doesn't allow strange combinations).Please, can you you give another look? Thanks! https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6qs1QnelGmyaG9qTGRFamk0WmM/edit

Comment: Note that this [screen shot](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8EDB73C8A1A37A69!471&authkey=!ABX74NahSNcovl4&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng) shows "Plum Yellow 17" but the only valid combinations seem to be "Plum Blue 3"; "plum yellow 11"; and "plum red 19".  To get there, make entries in D1:F1; then change the entry in D1.  Note that E1 and F1 do not change.

Comment: I think the problem was the list separator (in my case is ",") I putt now Application.International(xlListSeparator) instead. Please check: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6qs1QnelGmyaHlXdS1qRlY3NWc/edit

Comment: Same problem with this workbook.  And did you reproduce the problem I reported on your computer?

Comment: In my case(computer), it is working well! I do not know what is wrong.

Comment: What I say before with Application.International(xlListSeparator) is not correct because if I change in computer settings List separator "," to ";" and I use in code Application.International(xlListSeparator) instead of "," Data Validation List will not be created correct. (I am style looking to see what can be wrong)

Comment: I dont think the list separator is the problem. [from microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299490)

Comment: I have put together the steps I used to recreate the problem.  You can download the [DataValidationIssues](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8EDB73C8A1A37A69!473&authkey=!AEnmJzeZ6U1DYA8&ithint=file%2czip) file and see exactly what I am writing about.  If this is not a problem on your system, then there's not much more I can do.

Comment: but normally after when you change in cell D1 the value on cell E1 and F1 normally should be deleted this code is doing this (in my case)         Range("E1").ClearContents: Range("E1").Validation.Delete
        Range("F1").ClearContents: Range("F1").Validation.Delete

Comment: OK, now it is working.  When I downloaded the file, macros were disabled with no warning messages.  After re-enabling the macro, it seems to work OK now.  The next spot to test your approach would be to check the speed with the largest list you might be using; and if that is satisfactory, you should be OK.

Comment: I check on a different computer and it is working also there. Anyway, Thanks so much that you have putted time and effort for this.

Comment: Speed will not be an issue (It is not a large list, around 1000 lines). Got to go (he he, I have to wash dishes). Have a nice day (night)!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is setting up dependent validation lists to three levels.  The first two are relatively straightforward.  The third is complicated as you have to create a list for all valid combinations of the items in columns A and B.

That is what the routine below does; and, to keep myself from becoming overly confused :-), I set up a class object to create the "keys" for the tertiary list.  The keys, and title of the NAME'd range I created, are made up by concatenating a pipe-separated string of the first two entries.  The code for this is, I believe, easier to understand.

I set up the validation lists as named ranges on a separate worksheet titled "Lists", and then used Excel's Indirect function to decide which list to display (with regard to the secondary and tertiary levels).

Hopefully it will be relatively clear to you.

The Class module should be renamed "CLists"

The code below goes into the Class Module:

=======================================

```
Option Explicit
Private pPrimaryKey As String
Private pSecondaryKey As String

Public Property Get PrimaryKey() As String
    PrimaryKey = pPrimaryKey
End Property
Public Property Let PrimaryKey(Value As String)
    pPrimaryKey = Value
End Property

Public Property Get SecondaryKey() As String
    SecondaryKey = pSecondaryKey
End Property
Public Property Let SecondaryKey(Value As String)
    pSecondaryKey = Value
End Property
```

=====================================

Then this code goes into a regular module:

===========================================

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateDV()
    Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, R3 As Range
    Dim wsLists As Worksheet, wsMain As Worksheet
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim CL As CLists
    Dim colPrimary As Collection, colSecondary As Collection, colTertiary As Collection
    Dim colTertiaryKeys As Collection
    Dim vPrimary(), vSecondary(), vTertiary()
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long

Set wsMain = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsLists = Worksheets("Lists")

With wsMain
    V = .Range("a1", .Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp)).Resize(COLUMNSIZE:=3)
End With

'Create the lists
'Create the main list
Set colPrimary = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
    colPrimary.Add Item:=V(I, 1), Key:=CStr(V(I, 1))
Next I
ReDim vPrimary(0 To colPrimary.Count, 1 To 1)
vPrimary(0, 1) = "Primary"
For I = 1 To colPrimary.Count
    vPrimary(I, 1) = colPrimary(I)
Next I

'create secondary sublists
ReDim vSecondary(0 To UBound(V, 1), 1 To UBound(vPrimary, 1))
For I = 1 To UBound(vPrimary, 1)
    Set colSecondary = New Collection
    For J = 1 To UBound(V)
        If V(J, 1) = vPrimary(I, 1) Then _
            colSecondary.Add V(J, 2), CStr(vPrimary(I, 1) & V(J, 2))
    Next J
    vSecondary(0, I) = vPrimary(I, 1)
    For K = 1 To colSecondary.Count
        vSecondary(K, I) = colSecondary(K)
    Next K
Next I

'create tertiary sublists
'will need one list for each possible combination of the first two
'Generate List of Tertiary lists
Set colTertiaryKeys = New Collection
For I = 1 To UBound(vSecondary, 2)
    For J = 1 To UBound(vSecondary, 1)
        Set CL = New CLists
            If vSecondary(J, I) <> "" Then
        With CL
            .PrimaryKey = vSecondary(0, I)
            .SecondaryKey = vSecondary(J, I)
            colTertiaryKeys.Add CL
        End With
            End If
    Next J
Next I

ReDim vTertiary(0 To UBound(V, 1), 1 To colTertiaryKeys.Count)
For I = 1 To colTertiaryKeys.Count
    Set colTertiary = New Collection
    With colTertiaryKeys(I)
    For J = 1 To UBound(V, 1)
        If V(J, 1) = .PrimaryKey And _
            V(J, 2) = .SecondaryKey Then _
            colTertiary.Add V(J, 3), CStr(.PrimaryKey & "_" & .SecondaryKey & V(J, 3))
    Next J
    vTertiary(0, I) = .PrimaryKey & "_" & .SecondaryKey
    For K = 1 To colTertiary.Count
        vTertiary(K, I) = colTertiary(K)
    Next K
    End With
Next I

On Error GoTo 0

'Write the DV lists someplace and NAME them
'Primary list
With Worksheets("Lists")
    Set R1 = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(vPrimary, 1) + 1)
    Set R2 = .Cells(1, R1.Columns.Count + 2).Resize(UBound(vSecondary, 1) + 1, UBound(vSecondary, 2))
    Set R3 = .Cells(1, R2.Column + R2.Columns.Count + 2).Resize(UBound(vTertiary, 1) + 1, UBound(vTertiary, 2))
    .Cells.Clear
End With

R1 = vPrimary
R2 = vSecondary
R3 = vTertiary

'Create Named Lists
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
R1.CreateNames True, False, False, False
With R2
    For I = 1 To .Columns.Count
        Range(.Cells(1, I), .Cells(.Rows.Count, I).End(xlUp)).CreateNames True, False, False, False
    Next I
End With
With R3
    For I = 1 To .Columns.Count
        Range(.Cells(1, I), .Cells(.Rows.Count, I).End(xlUp)).CreateNames True, False, False, False
    Next I
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Add the DV schemes
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With wsMain
    With .Range("D1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=primary"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    'need something there or next cell errors out
    'with screenupdating off, this won't be seen, as we will delete it when done
    .Range("d1").Value = Range("primary")(1)

    With .Range("E1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=indirect(d1)"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    .Range("e1").Value = Range(Range("d1").Text)(1)

    With .Range("F1").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=indirect(d1 & ""_"" & e1)"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    .Range("D1:F1").ClearContents
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

=======================================

After playing with this for a while, it occurs to me that, whenever a change is made in D1:F1, the entries in the dependent lists should be cleared, else they will be "out of sync".  So the following code should be entered into the worksheet module code to catch that Change and blank the dependent cells, depending on which is changed.

=================================

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rDV As Range
Set rDV = Range("D1:E1")
If Not Intersect(rDV, Target) Is Nothing Then
    Target(1, 2).ClearContents
End If

End Sub
```

===================================

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for putting your time and experience on this. For the moment the code seams that has some problems (in my case). For example: add a new value in col A (give  error 1004), then on D1 and E1 can not be selected a different values (only the first one). I will try to digest your code tomorrow (now, here it is late, Belgium). Anyway, your code is a bit too much for my VBA experience (maybe a good sleep will gone help me). Thanks one more time!

Comment: For future reference, in this group you should make this kind of response in a comment, rather than in an "Answer".  With regard to your error message, do you still have the code in a worksheet module?  Or did you put it into a regular module as I wrote in my Answer.  Also, look back to my answer as I made a few changes in the code.  If it is working for you as is, we can discuss the issue of how you add information to the lists in columns A:C

Comment: Good-morning, I was putted the code in the correct way (like you pointed out) normal module, sheet-module, class module (Clists). But I think I am doing something wrong because it is not working. I will attach the file maybe you can give a look [excel file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6qs1QnelGmyNUlyNVdvTVZkZ00/edit)

Comment: One problem with your file was that you still had worksheet event code on the Lists worksheet.  But even after deleting that code, I was still getting strange errors, including errors Stack Overflow; and an inability to clear just a few cells.  I could not get things to work on your workbook.  Possibly it got corrupted.  Try this workbook: http://1drv.ms/1u6ktUT